# ThreaPool with LinkedBlockingQueue reject task when queue is empty

Tags: java, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I created a thread pool with following code

```
ThreadPoolExecutor backgroupTaskPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(100, 100, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS,  new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(100));
backgroupTaskPool.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
```

when submit tasks to this pool, it throws RejectedExecutionException, but the threads in the pool not reaches maximumPoolSize and the LinkedBlockingQueue is empty:

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@15e9aebd rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@7774348b[Shutting down, pool size = 9, active threads = 9, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 105]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2048)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:821)
```

Do you have any idea why could this happen?

THX.

Comment: How do you make sure that threads in the pool are not reached maximumPoolSize and LinkedBlockingQueue is empty. Show the code where you submit/execute threads. Seems like you are creating more threads than the maximum capacity.

Comment: It says the pool is shutting down.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the exception message

```
Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@15e9aebd rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@7774348b[Shutting down, pool size = 9, active threads = 9, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 105]
```

You seem to be shutting down the `ThreadPoolExecutor`. You can't submit tasks after you've called `shutdown`.

Comment: The ThreadPool is not shutdown. This is the exception if the thread pool is shutdown. `Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@1b1fbf4 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@148662[**Terminated**, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]`

Comment: @niklaus It takes time for a pool to shutdown. You seem to have submitted the task while that was going on. If you don't think so, please provide more context or code to reproduce the error.